# How make pyqt called two method by clicking one button

Tags: python, opencv, button, pyqt5

How to called two method when i'm clicking one button in PyQt

```
self.trainPreproBtn.clicked.connect(self.preproClicked, self.thresClicked)

@pyqtSlot()
def preproClicked(self):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    self.image = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(self.image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #resize_image = cv2.resize(im_bw, (180, 180))
    self.displayImage(2)
@pyqtSlot()
def thresClicked(self):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    self.image = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    self.image = cv2.threshold(self.image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
    self.displayImage(4)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function calling two other functions and connect it with the button.

```
self.trainPreproBtn.clicked.connect(self.connectionFunction)

@pyqtSlot()
def connectionFunction(self):
    self.firstFunction()
    self.secondFunction()
```

I never use @pyqtSlot() decorator in my scripts, but I assume it should be here since you use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call set 2 connections:

```
self.trainPreproBtn.clicked.connect(self.preproClicked)
self.trainPreproBtn.clicked.connect(self.thresClicked)
```